# Matplotlib throws UnicodeEncodeError while plotting simple numbers

Tags: python, matplotlib

I use anaconda for python2.7 packages like numpy, matplotlib etc.
Which is why I have to insert path at the beginning of my file.
The rest is the simplest possible code using plt.

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, "/home/mariusz/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages")

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot([1,2,3,4])
plt.ylabel('some numbers')
plt.show()
```

After I run it in Sublime Text 3 (with crl+b) an empty window is shown plus the following error:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-1: ordinal not in range(128)
```

As my backend (in patplotlibrc) I use TkAgg since all the other options simply show nothing. I coundn't find any reasonable solution online since all references to UnicodeEncodeError deal with special characters while I use simple numbers.

[image]

Also, it turns out that when I set backend to Qt4Agg the plot can be displayed by IDLE. So maybe the real question should be why doesn't Sublime display anything with `backend:Qt4Agg`.